# Wordpress permalinks first word title

Tags: permalinks

I'm trying to figure out how to trim or strip the permalinks of my post, I dunno where to look for in the file of wordpress or should I have to do this in functions.php which is safer?

e.g.

Title:FirstWord sentence sentence sentence sentence sentence
permalinks: site.com/FirstWord-sentence-sentence-sentence-sentence-sentence
while using the /%postname%/

then turn it into

site.com/FirstWord

Comment: Are you looking to do this for only one post?

Comment: All the existing post.